# 3D Print Failing With Extruder Not Extruding After a While

Tags: troubleshooting, extruder, bed-leveling, print-failure, qidi-tech-x-plus

I own a Qidi X-Plus 3D printer and have been trying to get it to print properly but to no avail. I've leveled the bed and have been fiddling with the Z-offset yet my prints still fail. Weirdly enough, the 3D prints seem to start off okay, however, after a while, they come out stringy, and then the extruder just stops extruding the filament altogether. I had something like this happen a while back which I sort of solved by adjusting the Z-offset but that doesn't seem to work now. Any ideas on why this happening?

Here are some failed prints:
[image]

[image]

I'm using the following print options:

- Retraction distance is 1.5 mm;
- Retraction speed is 38 mm/s;
- Printing temperature is 210 °C
- Building plate temperature is 75 °C (initial building plate temperature is 75 °C);
- Print speed is 60 mm/s; fan speed is at 100 %; and
- the Z-offset is at 0.06 mm

Comment: Hi Friend, welcome to 3DPrinting.SE! If I look at the image, it looks to me you are experiencing heat creep. Please update your question by [edit] to include some basic printing parameters. E.g. temperatures, printing speeds, retraction length and speed.

Comment: Hi @0scar, thanks for the welcome! My current settings are the following: Retraction distance is 1.5mm; retraction speed is 38 mm/s; printing temperature is 210 cel.; building plate temperature is 75 cel.; initial building plate temperature is 75 cel.; print speed is 60 mm/s; fan speed is at 100%; and the Z-offset is at 0.06. Hope this helps! : )